# What is a way to create a unique name for a file given it's name and a namespace value in the same directory?

Tags: file, namespaces, filesystems

I have to create a file name for a file that will exist with other files with the same or similar name in the same folder.

I have two values that will be used to define the name. The namespace and the class name.

So if there are a team of users and user A creates a Person class they have to give it a unique namespace name so if user B creates a Person class does not conflict with user A's class name.

Traditionally, namespaces are defined something like,

```
com.amazon.category.people
http://www.amazon.com/2022/categories/7.0.0
```

I'm ok with joining the namespace with the class name to create a unique phrase like so:

```
com.amazon.category.people::Person
```

BUT Here's the problem. When I'm creating a file, the filesystem doesn't like all those dots or colons Actually, I don't like them because multiple reasons. I thought about replacing all dots and colons with underscore.

```
com_amazon_category_people_Person.json
```

That's the best I've come up with. It won't work well with the other type of namespace:

```
http___www_amazon_com_2022_categories_7.0.0_Person
```

Are there any answers this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names containing dots aren't a problem for any OS, as far as I know. What you can do is either:

1. Put the files in a folder hierarchy, where every folder is the name of a namespace segment, like this:

```
+-me
| +-topchetoeu
| | +-myprogram
| |   +-Program.json
| +-somebodyelse
|   +-calculator
|     +-Add.json
|     +-Subtract.json
|     +-Divide.json
|     +-Multiply.json
+-com
  +-microsoft
    +-windows
      +-Spyware.json
```

Another solution would be to separate the namespace segments with dashes, and the class name with a `@` symbol, resulting in something like this:

```
me-topchetoeu-myprogram@Program.json
me-somebodyelse-calculator@Add.json
me-somebodyelse-calculator@Subtract.json
me-somebodyelse-calculator@Divide.json
me-somebodyelse-calculator@Multiply.json
com-microsoft-windows@Spyware.json
etc...
```

Comment: Does vscode have any issues with opening a file with the same name? Something like `com-example-calculator@Calculator.js`?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts not really, the @ symbol shouldn't be a problem for any editor. If it is, you could just use a dot instead.